# How to bring first input box value to second input box with refreshing and without saving into database?

Tags: php, html

[image]

How to bring the first input box value to second input box after clicks the confirm button and refreshing the page.

But I dont want to save the value in the database, I just want to bring the value from first input box to the second input box after clicks the confirm button and refreshing the page. The first input box value will show into the second input box.

After that, How should I pass the second input box value to another page?

Answer (score 0):

You have also a js API for cookies, cache and local/session storage, as well as IndexedDB, so you can use JS.

But why you need to refresh the page?? You could just put this value in a second field with JS without refreshing the page.

If you need badly to refresh the page after form validation, you have all form data sent by POST or GET, use the corresponding variables $_POST or $_GET in PHP and then echo wherever you want.

Or another option, if you need this value to be accessible all over your site/project and you use Sessions, you could save this value in the $_SESSION variable.

There are a lot of possible solutions, everything depends on your needs and goals.

Answer (score 0):

Put this into top of the file

```
$first_value = isset($_POST['first_input']) ? $_POST['first_input'] : "";
```

and this into the form

```
<form action="_white.php" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="first_input">
    <button>Confirm</button>
    <input type="text" name="second_input" value="<?php echo $first_value; ?>">

 </form>
```

It works

Comment: It works, but can bring the second input box value to the next page?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean